# .mouseover in jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mouseover

I'm trying to make a simple "one item fades out, another fades in" when the mouse is over an object function in jquery. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. 
Here's the js:

```
var fadeout = function(target) //fade out the logo and run fadein (fade in the skull)
{
$(target +' .logo').fadeTo(400,0,fadein(target));
};

var fadein = function(target) //fade in the skull 
{
    $(target +' .skull').fadeTo(500,1);
};

//trigger fadein when mouse is over an option 
$('#mortal').mouseover(fadeout('#mortal')); //mortal
```

When I examine the code in Chrome's console it works fine, but when I mouseover #mortal, nothing happens.

Here's the relevant HTML:

```
<div class="choice_option" id="mortal">
            <img class="logo" src="img\text\230px-WorldofDarknessLogo.png"></img>
            <img class="skull" src="img\skulls\mortal.png"></img>
</div>
```

and the relevant CSS:

```
.logo{ /* text logo in each choice_option */
position: absolute; 
z-index: 0;
}
.skull{ /* skull in each choice_option */
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
opacity: 0;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Use as `$('#mortal').on('mouseover',fadeout('#mortal')); //mortal`

Comment: Can you make fiddle for this

Comment: @Tyru  How about when you leave the image with the mouse. Should it not fade out to its original state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is very over complicated. You just need to use the `callback` parameter when setting up your `mouseover` handler. Try this:

```
$('#mortal').mouseover(function() {
    var $logo = $('.logo', this);
    var $skull = $('.skull', this);
    $logo.fadeOut(function() {
        $skull.fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Also, `img` tags should be self-closing:

```
<div class="choice_option" id="mortal">
    <img class="logo" src="img\text\230px-WorldofDarknessLogo.png" />
    <img class="skull" src="img\skulls\mortal.png" />
</div>
```

Finally, the `.skull` div should be `display: none`, not `opactiy: 0` for `fadeIn` or `fadeOut` to work.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zfzvx/)

Comment: Thanks, that actually works great and it is simpler :) I'm pretty new to js and this gives me a couple ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var fadeout = function(target) //fade out the logo and run fadein (fade in the skull)
    {
      $(target +' .logo').fadeTo(400,0,fadein(target));
    };

    var fadein = function(target) //fade in the skull 
    {
       $(target +' .skull').fadeTo(500,1);
    };

    $(document).on('mouseover', '#mortal', function(){
       fadeout('#mortal')
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#mortal').mouseenter(function() {
    fadeout('#mortal');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap your code in a function to make it work.

Its working ! http://jsfiddle.net/CYLcY/23/

```
.mouseover(
    function() {    alert('working !');
                    fadeout('#mortal')//mortal
               });
```

Answer (score 0):

use should wrap your code in a method firstly. another thing correctly write syntax for fade-in -fade out for particular object

`

```
$("#mortal").mouseover(function(){

$('.logo').hide();

});
```

`

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/caBzg/630/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the fadeout function in your mouseover. Like this:

```
$('#mortal').mouseover(function(){
    fadeout('#mortal');
}); //mortal
```